# Add picture's caption in left margin in refman class

Tags: captions, marginnote

I am using `refman` class in latex in order to write a manual of instructions. I would like to add pictures/diagrams with the caption in the left margin since it is quite wide but when I do it with the caption option of the figure environment the caption is placed below the picture and when I use `marginlabel{text of the caption}` it is aligned to the bottom of the picture and I'd rather have it aligned to the top of the picture.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{refart}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{img/bpa/bpa1.jpg} 
\caption{Text of the caption}
\end{figure}

\marginlabel{Text of the caption} \includegraphics[scale=1]{img/bpa/bpa1.jpg} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{refart}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}% for \captionof
\usepackage{mwe}% contains example-image

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newlength{\tempheight}

\begin{document}
% compute distance to align tops of text and image
\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image}}
\settoheight{\tempheight}{\usebox{\tempbox}}
\addtolength{\tempheight}{-0.6\baselineskip}

\marginlabel{Text of the caption } \raisebox{-\tempheight}{\usebox{\tempbox}}

% or actually simpler
\marginlabel{\captionof{figure}{Text of the caption} }
\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Do you happen to know if using a similar syntax I could put a small image in the left margin?

Comment: Anything in \marginlabel (that fits) will be placed there.

Comment: The thing is that the image will be aligned from the baseline not from top and if I use the figure environment in marginlabel it triggers an error.

Comment: First, \raisebox moves the baseline.  Second, you can use \newline inside \marginlabel.  Third, don't use the figure environment.  \captionof{figure} takes care of everything important.

Comment: of course, trying to center things inside the margin may prove difficult.